# Registry: Setting Child Permissions

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to set the permissions for a certain registry key and also set the same permissions to all of the child keys.  Setting the initial key's permissions is not problem but getting the rest to work is giving me a problem.

I created the following for test purposes:  HKLM\Software\1 with sub folders 2\3.

```
$REG = Get-Acl HKLM:\SOFTWARE\1
$Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule ("Everyone","FullControl","Allow")
$REG.SetAccessRule($Rule)
$REG |Set-Acl -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\1
$Dir = Get-Childitem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\1" -Recurse

foreach ($Folder in $Dir)
    {
    Write-Host $Folder
    Set-Acl $Folder $Reg
    }
```

When I do the Write-Host $Folder I get the proper subkey, but when it pushes it to Set-ACL I get the following error:

```
Set-Acl : Cannot find path 'C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Desktop\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\1\2\3' because it does not exist.
```

Working Solution:

```
$REG = Get-Acl HKLM:\SOFTWARE\1
$Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule ("Everyone","FullControl","Allow")
$REG.SetAccessRule($Rule)
$REG |Set-Acl -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\1
$Dir = Get-Childitem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\1" -Recurse

foreach ($Folder in $Dir)
    {
    $REG.SetAccessRule($Rule)
    $Reg | Set-Acl $Folder.PSPath 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the PSPath property [Tested on Windows 7 64-bit with Powershell ISE x86]-

```
$REG = Get-Acl HKLM:\SOFTWARE\1
$Dir = Get-Childitem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\1" -Recurse

foreach ($Folder in $Dir)
{
     Write-Host $Folder
     Set-Acl $Folder.PSPath $Reg
}
```

You can always figure out the supported members on an object like this -

```
foreach ($Folder in $Dir) 
{    
  $Folder | Get-Member 

}
```

I don't know if you are doing any other pre-processing with Get-ACL apart from what you have pasted.

> Check this link -
>   http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/09/15/hey-scripting-guy-september-15-2009.aspx.

Comment: It's throwing a new error now:

`Set-Acl : Cannot bind parameter 'AclObject'. Cannot convert the ".PSPath" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity"`

Comment: I checked. Its working fine on a Windows 7 - 64 Bit system running Powershell x86 ISE. Can u please re-check if there is any typo mistake ?

Comment: The code what you have pasted is working fine with my changes if I execute on my system. I don't know if you are doing any other kind of processing with Get-ACL. Check this link - http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/09/15/hey-scripting-guy-september-15-2009.aspx.

Comment: Sorry, got pulled away.  I had put a space between $Folder and .PSPath.  No longer getting the error but it's not sending the permissions down either.  Trying to figure that out right now.

Comment: Figured it out.  Needed to put add a line and change the second:

`$REG.SetAccessRule($Rule)
    $Reg | Set-Acl $Folder.PSPath`